# How to get the DATE format from Weekday name?

Tags: mysql, sql

In the **Week days**

```
Sunday=1
Monday=2
Tuesday=3
Wednesday=4
Thursday=5
Friday=6
Saturday=7
```

I have the current **string**

```
Saturdays at 13:35 PDT
```

I want to `INSERT` it into a `DATETIME` column to have its Day and Time only like this:

```
     DATETIME
0000-01-01 13:35:00  //Sundays at 13:35 PDT
0000-01-02 13:35:00  //Mondays at 13:35 PDT
0000-01-03 13:35:00  //Tuesdays at 13:35 PDT
0000-01-04 13:35:00  //Wednesdays at 13:35 PDT
0000-01-05 13:35:00  //Thursdays at 13:35 PDT
0000-01-06 13:35:00  //Fridays at 13:35 PDT
0000-01-07 13:35:00  //Saturdays at 13:35 PDT
```

---

I've thought about using the following

```
INSERT into TABLE(column) VALUES (STR_TO_DATE('Saturdays at 13:35', '%Ws at %H:%i'))
```

But it always gives me `NULL` value, Also I would like to change the **Timezone** from **PDT** to **UTC**, But I have no idea how with  `STR_TO_DATE()` function

Comment: I'm confused about the year in your DATETIME -- do you intend to have it as 0000?  Ie., do you always want the year to be 0000 and the month to be 01, and then the day of week to be 01 through 07 (based on Sunday through Saturday)?

Comment: @drewster Yes the Year will always be `0000`, because year `0001` give `01` day as `friday`.

Comment: Doesn't sound like a good use of datetime, as its not actually a date time. I think you would be better with a field DOW (day of week) and Time. The fact year zero happens to align is a bit of a coincidence. You may also find that this date will not always be acceptable by all downstream libraries. SQL Server for example would not allow it.

Comment: @TomC I don't think I can find `DOW` field type  in `MySQL`, Also wouldn't that prevent me from using the `Time` functionality?

Comment: No, I mean DOW as a column name. The column type would be a simple int. If you need to look up a name then have a small DAYNAME table as reference that. I would have the time as a separate column, of type TIME.

Comment: Just use two different columns, one for the day of the week and one for the time.

Comment: @TomC According to `MySQL` a `TINYINT`  field is `1 bytes` and a `TIME` field is `3 bytes`, yet `DATETIME` field is `8 bytes` which is twice in size of both previous fields types, Do I take these information and follow your recommendation as it follows the `Table Storage Requirements`? Or is there more I need to learn about?

Comment: The size of the fields is of less consideration than getting your model right. In this case if its smaller size as well then great. But never try and do things because they are smaller (unless you have a billion rows) if they dont make sense from a modelling point of view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a `CASE` for the weekdays might help with this.
Then `CONCAT` the time to it.

**Example :**

```
SELECT 
CONCAT(
  case SUBSTRING(weekday_at_time, 1, LOCATE(' ',weekday_at_time)-1)
  when 'Sundays' then '0000-01-01 '
  when 'Mondays' then '0000-01-02 '
  when 'Tuesdays' then '0000-01-03 '
  when 'Wednesdays' then '0000-01-04 '
  when 'Thursdays' then '0000-01-05 '
  when 'Fridays' then '0000-01-06 '
  when 'Saturdays' then '0000-01-07 '
  end, 
  STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING(weekday_at_time,length(weekday_at_time)-4,5),'%H:%i')
) AS "DATETIME"
FROM (
  -- Sample data
  select 'Sundays at 14:45' as weekday_at_time
  union all select 'Saturdays at 13:35'
) AS Samples
```

Test on SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/57062/0)

But that's assuming that you update it to a VARCHAR column.

Because a cast of a datetimestamp of the '0000' year to a datetime can give a different result.

For example:

```
select cast('0000-01-01 13:35:00' as datetime) as dt
```

Returns:

```
-0001-12-30T13:35:00Z
```

Changing the year to '1900' might be safer if you're updating to a DATETIME.
Test on SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1ac631/1/0)